# Is it possible to make such a request in django?

Tags: django, distinct, django-queryset

```
   name  |   date     | price
----------------------------
product1 | 01.02.2017 | 100
product1 | 03.02.2017 | 200*
product1 | 07.02.2017 | 300*
product2 | 02.02.2017 | 300
product2 | 04.02.2017 | 200*
product2 | 08.02.2017 | 200*
```

Count the number of products whose price has changed over the two dates. 
In example, answer: **1.**, becose only produc1 (200=>300), product2(200=200).

Comment: Anything you have tried so far?

Comment: I do not understand how to take the difference between the two lines (field price). is it even possible?

Comment: do you mean over two dates or over last two dates?

Comment: How to filter everything except the last two dates of each product.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure whether you can directly fetch what you desire with ORM, but you can always code it yourself.

Example steps:

1. Fetch the products for the first date
2. Fetch the products for the second date
3. Assuming that the products are the same and only the price has changed in a for loop check and compare the prices of the 2 queryset elements and keep a counter if they are different

Not the best solution, but something to work from. Hope this helps!

Comment: steps seems to be correct but if you add some code then it would be good

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I did not want to because OP hasn't given any namings that he uses, but I will put a general pseudo-ish code. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I also looked in this direction. Simply this decision is not very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above:

```
dates = Request.objects.all().values('date').order_by('-date').distinct()[:2] # last max 2 date

if dates.count() < 2:
    return None

requests = Request.objects.filter(date__in=dates).order_by(
    'product', 'price'
).distinct(
    'product', 'price'
).values('pk')

# can't requests.annotate() because .distinct()
products = Request.objects.filter(pk__in=requests).values('product').annotate(
    count=Count('product')
).filter(count__gt=1).values('product')

if not products.exists():
    return None

# return .all() or .count()
```

The only thing that I do not like:

```
.filter(pk__in=requests).
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The best workable solution I've been able to implement isn't as elegant as I would have hoped.

```
from collections import Counter
from datetime import date
from django.db.models import Count

date_from = date(2017, 2, 3)
date_to = date(2017, 2, 8)   

# this returns the products grouped by price and name.
# where there is more than one row of a product indicates
# a price change
reqs = Request.objects.filter(
        date__gte=date_from, 
        date__lte=date_to
    ).values(
        'product', 
        'price'
    ).annotate(
        count=Count('pk')
    ).order_by(
        'product', 
        'price'
    )

# count the occurrences of each row
counter = Counter(r['product'] for r in reqs)

# counts of two or more have had the price change.
products_price_changed = [p for p in counter if counter[p] > 1]
```

The result is a list of the product names that have changed. If you'd like to know how many have changed you can:

```
len(products_price_changed)
```